# How to measure the percentage of files that were compiled successfully?

Tags: c, linux, compilation

I am working on porting a large piece of software to a new platform, and basically at this point all I am doing is fixing compilation errors I stumble upon. My management is asking me "how far you've got?" - how can I measure how much I was able to compile successfully and how much is to go?

This is c sources only, and the logs I get from 'make' are so insanely stuffed, that I don't even know what to grep to find this out.

Comment: How many source file are building successfully? How many are there is total? While you might not get errors from all that are left, that's seems to be the only metric you can provide. And it's a pretty stupid metric to begin with, which you (in diplomatic terms) should put forward to your project manager (in mail or some other medium that can be pointed to later), and then let the project manager deal with the higher up bosses.

Comment: you could write tests and count the number of greens you get. Given the huge spread in the size of source files imho the number of succesfully compiled files is not a good measure of progress

Comment: The quick way (probably some hour of work still) is to toss the whole project into an IDE that allows single file (translation unit) compilation. Go through all C files and compile that file alone, one at a time. Then simply count how many that compiled and how many that didn't. Some IDEs even have the option to compile the whole project and then display some manner of icon next to the files that didn't compile.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd naively compare the number of .cpp files and .o files:

```
#!/bin/bash

number_of_sources=$(find . -name \*.cpp | wc -l)
number_of_objects=$(find . -name \*.o   | wc -l)
progress=$(echo "${number_of_objects} * 100 / ${number_of_sources}" | bc)
echo "${progress}% of translation units successfully compiled."
```

This would need adaption related to your context (some subpath not to look into like `.git/`, some renaming, ...)

Comment: worked like a charm (but I changed extension to .c), thanx! (and to all - yes, I agree it is not a very useful metric, but I got 68%, having spent a few days on this, so it's something)

Comment: @niralittle Managers genuinely need metrics. And better a slightly inaccurate metric than no metric at all.

Comment: Downvoters, please say why so I could improve my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have a generic target to compile c++ files to object files, you can make some adjustments to the makefile to make it count compilations for you:

```
SHELL=/bin/bash
[...]
COMPILED_FILES=0

all:
    #whatever you do to compile object files together
    echo "Total number of compiled files: " $(COMPILED_FILES)

%.o:%.cpp
    #whatever you do to compile to object file
    $(eval COMPILED_FILES=$(shell echo $$(($(COMPILED_FILES)+1))))
```

The `eval` line can be understood from [this questions selected answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34142638/makefile-how-to-increment-a-variable-when-you-call-it-var-in-bash).